# How to `touch` and `cat` file named `-`

Tags: linux, cat, touch

How do I use GNU `touch` to update a file called `-`?

How do I use GNU `cat` to display a file called `-`?

---

I'm running:

```
% cat --version | head -n1
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.29
% touch --version | head -n1
touch (GNU coreutils) 8.29
```

Firstly, `touch`:

```
% touch -
% ls -l
total 0
% touch -- -
% ls -l -- -
ls: cannot access '-': No such file or directory
```

Ok, I'll give up on creating a file with `touch`. Let's create it with `date` instead:

```
% date > -
% ls -l -
-rw-r--r-- 1 ravi ravi 29 Sep  8 19:54 -
%
```

Now, let's try to `cat` it:

```
% cat -
% # I pressed ^D
% cat -- -
% # Same again - I pressed ^D
```

I know I can work around with:

```
% > -
```

and

```
% cat < -
```

But why don't these GNU utils support the convention that `--` means that everything following is treated as a non-option?

How do I use these tools in the general case, for example I have a variable with the contents `-`?

Comment: @Barmar This is a more specific case where the filename is `-`.  A lone `-` is not an option, so the issue is different from the issues in the questions that you have proposed as duplicates.

Comment: @Kusalananda A lone `-` is going to be treated as an invalid option or a placeholder for `stdin` or `stdout`. In any case, the *solution* is the same.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, but `-` is not an invalid option.

Comment: @Kusalananda If it's not treated as a synonym for stdin/stdout (as `touch` and `cat` do), and it's not a filename, and it's not an actual option, what else could it be? But this is immaterial, my point is that you use the same solution to deal with any filename beginning with `-`, it doesn't matter why it doesn't work normally.

Comment: Forget off the top of my head, but ti was covered in this "game" that teaches you escaping stuff, etc.  Really like this series they have for learning a higher level of command line use... and I've been using Linux for 20 years... http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit0.html

Comment: @Barmar It's not an invalid option. If the utility does not recognise it as a special file name operand (as `cat`) does, and if there is no file with the filename `-` in the current directory, then the utility should complain about "no such file or directory". I'm totally OK with the dup votes though.

Comment: @Kusalananda `touch` doesn't complain `no such file or directory`, since it creates new files.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, but GNU `touch` also recognise `-` as special, and I said that if the utility didn't do that, _then_ it may complain, especially if it treats it as the name of a file to read from. Unrelated to that, I'm noticing that BSD `sort -o -` treats `-` as stdout, while GNU `sort` does not (while both implementations treat `sort -` as reading from stdin). Interesting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an explicit path to the file:

```
touch ./-
cat ./-
```

GNU `touch` treats a file operand of `-` specially:

> A FILE argument string of `-` is handled specially and causes `touch` to
>          change the times of the file associated with standard output.

For `cat`, [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cat.html) specifies that a file operand `-` should be interpreted as a request to read from standard input.

The double-dash convention is still in effect, but it's not for signalling the end of *arguments* but the end of *options*.  In neither of these cases would `-` be taken as an option (a lone `-` can not be an option) but as an operand ("file name argument").

---

Regarding your last question:

To protect the contents of a variable against being interpreted as a set of options when using it as

```
utility "$variable"
```

use

```
utility -- "$variable"
```

Note that if the utility is `cat`, `sed`, `awk`, `paste`, `sort` and possibly a few others (or GNU `touch`), and `$variable` is `-`, this will still cause the utility to do its special processing since, as said above, `-` is not an option.  Instead, make provisions so that filenames, if they may start with or are equal to `-`, are preceded by a path, for example `./` for files in the current working directory.

A good habit is to use

```
for filename in ./*; do
```

rather than

```
for filename in *; do
```

for example.

Comment: It seems the way for absolute belts and braces would be to do `cat "$(readlink -f "$file")"`

Comment: What about the `touch` case though?

Comment: @TomHale no. `readlink -f` is not portable. What about the `touch` case?

Comment: So `[ "$file" = - ] && file=./-` is needed before each invocation of GNU `cat` and `touch` for the truly paranoid? Any nicer ways?

Comment: @TomHale If you're looping over files in a directory, make a habit of using `for file in ./*` or similar, instead of `for file in *`.

Comment: @TomHale, Also `"$(readlink -f -- "$file")"` (here adding the missing `--`) strips trailing newline characters so wouldn't work for files that end in newline. Also note that with GNU `readlink` at least, `readlink -f foo/bar` where `foo` doesn't exist  returns an empty output, exit status 1 and no error message.