# Why doesn't var=- work?

Tags: zsh

In writing the question:

[How to `touch` and `cat` file named `-`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467710/143394)

I was trying to generalise to a case where a file named `-` was stored in a variable.

In `zsh`, I tried setting a variable to contain a single hyphen:

```
% var=-
% echo $var

% var='-'
% echo $var

% var=\-
% echo $var

%
```

Why don't these work?

Why is `zsh` different to `bash` in this regard?

How do I set `$var` to `-`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Again, as often, it's not the value actually in the variable, but how the variable is. The `echo` in this case. Zsh's `echo` takes the single dash as an end of options indicator, so it's removed. [Online manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

> Note that for standards compliance a double dash does not terminate option processing; instead, it is printed directly. However, a single dash does terminate option processing, so the first dash, possibly following options, is not printed, but everything following it is printed as an argument. **The single dash behaviour is different from other shells.** For a more portable way of printing text, see *printf*, and for a more controllable way of printing text within zsh, see *print*.

So we have:

```
zsh% echo -

zsh% echo - -n
-n
zsh% var=-
zsh% printf "%s\n" "$var"
-
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

Comment: So this needs to be seen as a bug in `zsh`.

Comment: @schily, sure, go ahead and report is as such.

Comment: See also: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2018/msg00202.html

Comment: @schily : I wouldn't see it as a bug. The behaviour is exactly as documented in the zsh man page. Note that if you don't like this behaviour of the `echo` builtin in Zsh, you can always use, i.e., `command echo $var` instead of `echo $var` and your dash will be printed.

Comment: @user1934428, using the system's `echo` will not necessarily help. For instance, on GNU systems, you'll still have problems for values of `$var` like `-n`, `--version`, `-Ene`... In `zsh`, `echo -E - $var`, `print -r -- $var` and `printf '%s\n' "$var"` should be equivalent but only the latter one is portable to other Bourne-like shells which is why zsh and POSIX recommend to use `printf` here.  Only zsh and yash `echo`s are able to output arbitrary data.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Sorry to disagree in this point, but I tried it on Cygwin (which is, admittedly, not Linux, but at least the utilities are GNU based), and `/bin/echo -` outputs does output a dash. Right now, I also have access to some (somewhat older) Linux, and here too, it works. Could you cite a source which would explain why my approach wouldn't work?

Comment: @user1934428, yes, that `echo -` handling is specific to `zsh` (some old versions of pdksh output nothing on `echo -` but that was a bug then). I was pointing out that GNU `echo` (and most other `echo` implementations) have issues of their own, not on `-` but other values of `$var` like `--version`, `-nene`... So using another `echo` **in general** is not the best solution.